# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected TVAL_ID, expecting TOK_SETTEXTURE or '}'

Tags: unity, unity2d, compilar

Tengo un error en unity que esta en todos mis shaders y no se como resolverlo. El error se indica en la 16 de casi todos los shaders. Los shaders muestran en pantalla en 2D.
Este error me ha surgido sacando el código de un minijuego usando utinyripper. Dejo algunos enlaces con gente que ha tenido problemas parecidos:

https://gitter.im/UtinyRipper/Lobby?at=5c9a76e081b15c5e4b8e986b

https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/com.unity.perception/issues/392

https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity2D/comments/7s87pq/help_with_simple_shader/

https://solveforum.com/forums/threads/solved-parse-error-in-unity-shader-file-not-sure-what-it-is.189906/

Este es uno de mis códigos de los shaders:

```
Properties {
_MainTex ("Base (RGB), Alpha (A)", 2D) = "black" {}
}
SubShader { 
LOD 200
Tags { "QUEUE"="Transparent" "IGNOREPROJECTOR"="true" "RenderType"="Transparent" }
Pass {
Tags { "QUEUE"="Transparent" "IGNOREPROJECTOR"="true" "RenderType"="Transparent" }
ZWrite Off
Cull Off
Fog { Mode Off }
Blend One OneMinusSrcAlpha
ColorMask RGB
Offset -1, -1
Program "vp" {
SubProgram "gles " {
"!!GLES


#ifdef VERTEX

attribute vec4 _glesVertex;
attribute vec4 _glesColor;
attribute vec4 _glesMultiTexCoord0;
uniform highp mat4 glstate_matrix_mvp;
uniform highp vec4 _ClipRange0;
varying mediump vec4 xlv_COLOR;
varying highp vec2 xlv_TEXCOORD0;
varying highp vec2 xlv_TEXCOORD1;
void main ()
{
gl_Position = (glstate_matrix_mvp * _glesVertex);
xlv_COLOR = _glesColor;
xlv_TEXCOORD0 = _glesMultiTexCoord0.xy;
xlv_TEXCOORD1 = ((_glesVertex.xy * _ClipRange0.zw) + _ClipRange0.xy);
}



#endif
#ifdef FRAGMENT

uniform sampler2D _MainTex;
uniform highp vec4 _ClipArgs0;
varying mediump vec4 xlv_COLOR;
varying highp vec2 xlv_TEXCOORD0;
varying highp vec2 xlv_TEXCOORD1;
void main ()
{
mediump vec4 col_1;
highp vec2 tmpvar_2;
tmpvar_2 = ((vec2(1.0, 1.0) - abs(xlv_TEXCOORD1)) * _ClipArgs0.xy);
lowp vec4 tmpvar_3;
tmpvar_3 = texture2D (_MainTex, xlv_TEXCOORD0);
mediump vec4 tmpvar_4;
tmpvar_4 = (tmpvar_3 * xlv_COLOR);
highp float tmpvar_5;
tmpvar_5 = clamp (min (tmpvar_2.x, tmpvar_2.y), 0.0, 1.0);
highp float tmpvar_6;
tmpvar_6 = (tmpvar_4.w * tmpvar_5);
col_1.w = tmpvar_6;
highp vec3 tmpvar_7;
tmpvar_7 = mix (vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), tmpvar_4.xyz, vec3(tmpvar_5));
col_1.xyz = tmpvar_7;
gl_FragData[0] = col_1;
}



#endif"
}
SubProgram "gles3 " {
"!!GLES3#version 300 es


#ifdef VERTEX

in vec4 _glesVertex;
in vec4 _glesColor;
in vec4 _glesMultiTexCoord0;
uniform highp mat4 glstate_matrix_mvp;
uniform highp vec4 _ClipRange0;
out mediump vec4 xlv_COLOR;
out highp vec2 xlv_TEXCOORD0;
out highp vec2 xlv_TEXCOORD1;
void main ()
{
gl_Position = (glstate_matrix_mvp * _glesVertex);
xlv_COLOR = _glesColor;
xlv_TEXCOORD0 = _glesMultiTexCoord0.xy;
xlv_TEXCOORD1 = ((_glesVertex.xy * _ClipRange0.zw) + _ClipRange0.xy);
}



#endif
#ifdef FRAGMENT

out mediump vec4 _glesFragData[4];
uniform sampler2D _MainTex;
uniform highp vec4 _ClipArgs0;
in mediump vec4 xlv_COLOR;
in highp vec2 xlv_TEXCOORD0;
in highp vec2 xlv_TEXCOORD1;
void main ()
{
mediump vec4 col_1;
highp vec2 tmpvar_2;
tmpvar_2 = ((vec2(1.0, 1.0) - abs(xlv_TEXCOORD1)) * _ClipArgs0.xy);
lowp vec4 tmpvar_3;
tmpvar_3 = texture (_MainTex, xlv_TEXCOORD0);
mediump vec4 tmpvar_4;
tmpvar_4 = (tmpvar_3 * xlv_COLOR);
highp float tmpvar_5;
tmpvar_5 = clamp (min (tmpvar_2.x, tmpvar_2.y), 0.0, 1.0);
highp float tmpvar_6;
tmpvar_6 = (tmpvar_4.w * tmpvar_5);
col_1.w = tmpvar_6;
highp vec3 tmpvar_7;
tmpvar_7 = mix (vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), tmpvar_4.xyz, vec3(tmpvar_5));
col_1.xyz = tmpvar_7;
_glesFragData[0] = col_1;
}



#endif"
}
}
Program "fp" {
SubProgram "gles " {
"!!GLES"
}
SubProgram "gles3 " {
"!!GLES3"
}
}
}
}
SubShader { 
LOD 100
Tags { "QUEUE"="Transparent" "IGNOREPROJECTOR"="true" "RenderType"="Transparent" }
Pass {
Tags { "QUEUE"="Transparent" "IGNOREPROJECTOR"="true" "RenderType"="Transparent" }
ZWrite Off
Cull Off
Fog { Mode Off }
Blend One OneMinusSrcAlpha
ColorMask RGB
ColorMaterial AmbientAndDiffuse
Offset -1, -1
SetTexture [_MainTex] { combine texture * primary }
}
}
}
```

No se como podría solucionarlo ya que estoy muy perdido en este tema, si alguien podría saber la solución les estaría muy agradecido.
Os dejo una captura del error en el editor

[image: Aqui esta la captura con el error]